# SQL write query that show the skipping between dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, northwind

I try to write a query that will find hops by showing the date before the start of the jump and the first date after the skip.

I tried:

```
SELECT OrderDate FROM Orders
```

and I got:

[image]

but I don't succeed to split them to gaps like this:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: I don't mean to rude here, but you are asking a series of questions that you have admitted is homework. Rather than trying once and then coming to SO you would learn far more by doing some research and making more attempts. Personally I think you would be better off asking about the functions or documentation you don't understand; what's happening here is that we're effectively completing your homework for you. You won't learn anything that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use can use `dense_rank()` to generate a sequence.  When you subtract this from the date, you will identify adjacent sequential dates.

So:

```
select min(orderdate), max(orderdate)
from (select o.*, dense_rank() over (order by orderdate) as seqnum
      from orders o
     ) o
group by dateadd(day, -seqnum, orderdate)
order by min(orderdate);
```

You need `dense_rank()` because your data has duplicates.

EDIT:

To find jumps, use `LEAD()`:

```
select dateadd(day, 1, orderdate),
       dateadd(day, -1, next_orderdate)
from (select orderdate, lead(orderdate) over (order by orderdate) as next_orderdate
      from (select distinct orderdate orders o) o
     ) o
where next_orderdate > dateadd(day, 1, orderdate);
```

Comment: This is the "Islands" solution for [gaps and islands](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/), I think the OP wants the Gaps.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you! I try to find only the gaps that grather than 1 like 1996-07-05 -> 1996-07-08, what do I need to change in the WHERE?

Comment: @eliadchoen . . . I changed the `<>` to `>`. You can just adjust the `1` to change the minimum gap size that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with cte as (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY OrderDate) as row_num,OrderDate from orders)
select 
curr.OrderDate as Gap_start, 
nex.OrderDate as Gap_end
from 
cte curr
left join
cte nex
on
curr.row_num = nex.row_num - 1;
```